# Trimming an output

Tags: powershell

I am runing a command to get an active Network connection and I am getting the output in below format.

```
PS C:\> wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%'" get netconnectionid
NetConnectionID
Local Area Connection

PS C:\>
```

But I want the output only as Local Area Connection , Can anyone help me to trim that ?

Comment: `(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter).netconnectionid`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Select-String to get a particular string like:

```
wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%'" get netconnectionid | Select-String "Local Area Connection"
```

Comment: Is there any other methord to do this ? the reason being, the network adapter name is different in each machine it can be Ethernet/Local Area Connection etc .

Comment: So what exactly you wish to pick ? you are looking for Local Area Connection or Ethernet condition? So whichever is present you can pick? is that what you have meant?

Comment: when I use this commandlike below , I am getting the output as I wish, But its not removing the white space. wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%'" get netconnectionid | Select -Skip 1

Comment: you can use `(Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter").Name`

Comment: corrected myself and this works for me wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%'" get netconnectionid | Select -Skip 1 | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" }

Comment: Thanks All for helping me with this

Comment: If you want this to be accepted, edit your answer so this is part of the answer. Right now the part that works is ***not*** actually part of the answer.

Comment: i got the upvote cause its quite beneficial for him. thats enough. he understood at the end, that matters.